# How does an event based system handle multiple events from multiple threads coming in at the same time on a multi-core system?

Tags: multithreading, events, concurrency, parallel-processing

say we have a program that creates threads on a parallel multi-thread system to count words in a file by splitting the file into sections and having each thread count the words in that section. If we have an event based system on the main thread that should accept these partial sums  (to add them up), how would a system handle multiple threads finishing at the same time and generating an "event". I understand that if the threads finished at different times, they could just be added to a queue to be processed on the main thread, but if multiple parallel threads are finishing at the same time, how can they push to this queue without interfering/overwriting each other?

Comment: What do you mean by "event based system"? I do not understand where is the problem: each thread can just push the information in an atomic queue. The fact that thread finish is independent to the received event (but may be important for a given implementation of the whole system).

Comment: I'm not exactly sure to be honest. I think event based systems are used to solve concurrency issues, so I guess if you wanted to use an event based system, how would you propose it would work given the requirements? Another thing that might help me understand is if you explained the atomic queue a little more. How would multiple threads access this atomic queue and how would the atomicity of the queue be guaranteed. Would some sort of lock like a mutex be needed for this?

Comment: "if multiple parallel threads are finishing at the same time, how can they push to this queue without interfering/overwriting each other?" - Adding information to an "event queue" (whatever it means) could be protected with atomic variables, mutexes, spinlocks, etc. The actual implementation is OS-specific. If you want to know how such queue **could** be implemented, then take any OS and examine its code. In the current form your question is quite broad.